# SublimeText2+HTML: Cursor positioning when creating new elements using "tab" shortcut

Tags: sublimetext2

I could not think of an efficient title for my question so I apologize for any confusion there.

This question is specific to sublime text 2 (because that is the only editor I have used).

When I create a new element (div for example) I will type div.class-name + "tab" and it will generate the following (with the "*" represents cursor location):

```
    <div class="class-name">*</div>
```

As shown, the cursor will be conveniently located in-between the opening and closing braces of the div.

I then hit return twice to bring to open some space to put text or more elements inside of the div so it looks like this (again "*" represents cursor location):

```
    <div class="class-name">

    *</div>
```

I then hit "up" on my keyboard to bring my cursor up as shown here:

```
    <div class="class-name">
*
    </div>
```

Then I hit "tab" to bring my cursor forward but it jumps down to the end of the /div:

```
    <div class="class-name">

    </div>*
```

I then have to hit "up" again, then "tab" and then it jumps to the position I want it to go.

```
    <div class="class-name">
          *
    </div>
```

Is there a more efficient way to create an element, open it up over a line or 2 and get my cursor inside of the element to add more code?

Answer (score 1):

I am using sublime text 3 and the behaviour is as expected. See below. It may be worth upgrading to Sublime Text 3.

[image]

Comment: that looks much better. I'll definitely upgrade